# Script cannot find button using xpath or id or anything else through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm pretty new at using Python but this seems like a pretty straight forward script I'm trying to write. I have been able to log-in to the website properly, but to get to the next step I am trying to click on a button that says "Market Express".

I am able to see the xpath (//*[@id="MarketExpress"]) as well as the button's id (MarketExpress). When I run the module I receive this error: "Unable to locate element: //*[@id="MarketExpress"]"

I have even double checked the xpath using Firefox's addon "xpath finder" to make sure I have the right code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

usernameStr = '***'
passwordStr = '***'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(('https://www.myurl.com'))

username = driver.find_element_by_id('USERID')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'currentPassword')))
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
nextButton = driver.find_element_by_id('submit-button')
nextButton.click()

password = driver.find_element_by_name('currentPassword')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
nextButton = driver.find_element_by_name('Submit')
nextButton.click()

marketExpress = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MarketExpress"]').click();
```

I have tried so many different things but cannot get the script to click this button, I would appreciate any help!

Below is the html where the button is:

```
<input class="crtordbtn" type="button" value="Market Express" `id="MarketExpress" onclick="parent.location.href='/OMAPX?userId=051220665&amp;clientId=8&amp;UserType=null&amp;BuyerCookie=null';">`
```

Below is the table where I believe the button is in:

```
 <div id="sidebar-left" height="50%" style="margin-right:10px">
<div id="bar" style="margin-right:-3px"><h1>Select To Order</h1></div>

<div style="width:100%; height:50%; border-left:1px solid #cccccc;border-right:1px solid #cccccc;border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;margin-bottom:10px;"> 

 <table width="235px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

 <!--  <tr align="center">
 <td style="padding: 5px 40px 0px 40px;">


 <input class="crtordbtn" type="button" value="eSysco Express" id="esyscoExpress" onClick="parent.location.href='http://flex2.esysco.net';" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
 <td style="padding: 5px 40px 0px 40px;text-align:left">
 <p>Our latest order management application with improved performance and enhanced usability</p>
</td>
</tr>-->

<tbody><tr align="center">

    <td style="padding: 5px 40px 0px 40px;">

            <input class="crtordbtn" type="button" value="Market Express" id="MarketExpress" onclick="parent.location.href='/OMAPX?userId=051220665&amp;clientId=8&amp;UserType=null&amp;BuyerCookie=null';">


    </td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding: 5px 40px 0px 40px;text-align:left">
        <p>Our latest order management application with improved performance and enhanced usability</p>
    </td></tr>
    <tr>



</tr>

</tbody></table>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.crtordbtn#MarketExpress[onclick*='OMAPX?userId']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='crtordbtn' and @id='MarketExpress'][contains(@onclick, 'OMAPX?userId')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: The best way for dynamic elements is `WebDriverWait`!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I received an error when trying the CSS_SELECTOR method: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette, getting the same error for XPATH as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It should work.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='esyscoExpress']/tbody/tr//input[@class='crtordbtn']").click()
```

Comment: Getting about the same error: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@class='crtordbtn']

Comment: Then it must be under any frame or table could please check the input tag present inside any frame

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I check the input tag present inside any frame?

Comment: If you go to your html source code just search iframe.

Comment: However I have tested your html input on my machine and it is working with my code.That is why I am wondering any iframe is there.

Comment: There are no matches for "iframe"

Comment: The button might be inside this frame but this id didn't work either:   <tr align="center">
 <td style="padding: 5px 40px 0px 40px;">


 <input class="crtordbtn" type="button" value="eSysco Express" id="esyscoExpress" onClick="parent.location.href='http://flex2.esysco.net';" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
 <td style="padding: 5px 40px 0px 40px;text-align:left">
 <p>Our latest order management application with improved performance and enhanced usability</p>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: If button is there inside frame then you have to switch to frame first and then only above code will work.

Comment: How do I switch to the frame first? I have never done that.

Comment: Can you please post the table id which <tr> you have posted in previous comment

Comment: It looks like its id = "esyscoExpress"

Comment: I am editing my answer please confirm whether it worked.

Comment: Same error: "Message: Unable to locate element: //table[@id='esyscoExpress']/tbody/tr//input[@class='crtordbtn']"

Comment: Strange.Are you sure the table id = "esyscoExpress" ?

Comment: can you please paste the table here before I go to bed?

Comment: I added it to the bottom of my original post. I believe that is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps trying with the id will work. Hope it helps

```
driver.find_element_by_id("MarketExpress").click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot find the ID either.